# How to delete entire column including header if all rows contain the value 0

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with headers in row 1 and values for each of those columns from -2 to 2 in the subsequent rows. I would like to delete a column (including the header) if each row contains the value 0.

Example: I have three columns A, B, and C and 1500 rows. The header for each of these rows are Patient 1, Patient 2, and Patient 3. Patient 3 contains 0 in each of the 1499 rows and I want to have a final spreadsheet with just Patient 1 and Patient 2.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure if you need this done though automation or if you just don't want to scan each column..... but `=IF(COUNTIF(C2:C1500,"=0")=rows(C2:C1500),"DELETE","KEEP")` at the bottom of each colum (adjusting range for your ranges) would tell you what you need to do.  It basically says if the count of 0's in teh coulumns matches the count of rows then show delete.

Comment: I have several thousand columns as well so I'd like to automate the deletion if possible. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Ah so you need a macro /vba then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Sub RemoveZeroBasedColumns()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Dim iLastCol As Integer
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iC As Integer

    With oWS

        iLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        For iC = 1 To iLastCol
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Chr(64 + iC) & ":" & Chr(64 + iC)), 0) = iLastRow Then
                .Columns(iC).Delete shift:=xlShiftToLeft
                iLastCol = iLastCol - 1
            End If
        Next


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Zac I receive the following error when trying to run that: Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range

Comment: Which line did you get the error on? Make sure that it is pointing to the correct sheet